# Renaming "extensional-equality" to "extensional-type-theory"

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

Is there any better suggestion or reasons against changing [extensional-equality](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extensional-equality) to [extensional-type-theory](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extensional-type-theory)? [As Couchy suggests](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/1395/normalization-by-evaluation-for-extensional-type-theories), the current tag is slightly ambiguous. If there is no objection, I think I will take the liberty to do it.

---

I did the renaming. There seems to be an error occurring when I try to use the merge tool. So I did it by hand.

Comment: If in doubt, just create the tag and see if it catches on?